# python, zeromq and pub/sub - remote sub is not getting data

Tags: python, zeromq

On my publisher I use the below to send data.

```
context_forward2 = zmq.Context()
forward2_socket = context_forward2.socket(zmq.PUB)
forward2_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:7002")
transpport = 'orderbook stuff'
forward2_socket.send(transpport)
```

On my subscriber server...

```
context = zmq.Context()
forward_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
forward_socket.connect("tcp://89.55.55.55:7002")
forward_socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'orderbook')
time.sleep(5)
while True:
    print 'a'
    transpport = forward_socket.recv()
    print 'b'
    transpport = transpport.split('orderbook ')[1]
    print 'c'
    print transpport
```

But issue is that is just hangs at transpport = forward_socket.recv()

Why will zeromq not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want outside world to connect in. You need to bind `89.55.55.55` or `0.0.0.0` (but not `127.0.0.1`, it only listen local tcp package)

Answer (score 0):

Add `time.sleep(5)` right before the `socket.send()` in the publisher. You need to establish a connection between publishers and subscribers before transmitting data. Your issue is a timing issue.

The following programs work as expected for me:

Publisher:

```
import zmq 
import time
context_forward2 = zmq.Context()
forward2_socket = context_forward2.socket(zmq.PUB)
forward2_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:7002")
transpport = 'orderbook stuff'
time.sleep(5)
forward2_socket.send(transpport)
```

Subscriber:

```
import zmq 
import time
context = zmq.Context()
forward_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
forward_socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:7002")
forward_socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'orderbook')
time.sleep(5)
while True:
  print 'a' 
  transpport = forward_socket.recv()
  print transpport
  print 'b' 
  transpport = transpport.split('orderbook ')[1]
  print 'c' 
  print transpport
```

(with your static IP address replaced with 127.0.0.1 because I'm testing on a local machine)